# How to get the first visible group key in the grouped listview

Tags: wpf, listview, grouping

I have a ListView which is grouped by the datetime field of the items in the itemsource. I want to get the group key of the top item visible. Also, I would like to get the changed group key as soon as a new item is scrolled to the top of the listview. How can I achieve it?

Code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public DateTime DateTimePropertyOfClassA { get; set; }
}

public class MyVM
{
    public MyVM()
    {
        //return a grouped collection:
        Grouped = from x in CollectionOfClassA group x by x.DateTimePropertyOfClassA into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;
    }

    public IList<ClassA> CollectionOfClassA { get; set; } = new List<ClassA>()
    {
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA =DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01")}
        };

        public IEnumerable<object> Grouped { get; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs"
                              IsSourceGrouped="True"
                              Source="{x:Bind MyVM.Grouped, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Could you post code please?